Proof for Convolution on Periodic Grid Delta Functions
While I originally wrote my question here, I suddenly understood how to show the proposition. I would love to have the community check if it is sufficient.

I am currently reading Classical Numerical Analysis by Abner J. Salgado and Steven M. Wise.
On page 349 the authors give the following proposition

Proposition Convolution 
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\delta_{j}^{n,p} \in \mathcal{V}_{n,p}(\mathbb{C})$. Furthermore, for any $u \in \mathcal{V}_{n,p}(\mathbb{C})$ it follows that
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}u_{j}\delta_{j-k}^{n,p} = u_{k} \tag*{$\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$}$$

For completeness I will also give the following definition

Definition Periodic Grid Delta Function 
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The periodic grid delta function, denoted $\delta^{n,p} \in \mathcal{V}(\mathbb{C})$, is defined via
$$\delta_{j}^{n,p}=\begin{cases}
 1, &\exists m \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ such that } j=mn \\
 0, &\forall m \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ such that } j\neq mn \\
\end{cases} \tag*{$\forall j \in \mathbb{Z}$}$$

Now, wanting to prove the proposition it seems glaring, that all $\delta^{n,p}_{j-k}=0$ if $j \neq k$. So this is my strategy showing this proposition.


Proof
We first note
$$\delta_{j-k}^{n,p} = 1 \iff j-k = nm \iff j \equiv k \;\;(\text{mod } n)$$
Hence, any integer $k$ which is equivalent to $j$ yields $\delta_{j-k}^{n,p} = 1$.  Without loss of generality we restrict $k\geq 0$.
 Case 1: $k<n$
The only number equivalent integer to $k$ with respect to modulus $n$ is $k$ itself, by definition of residue classes. We conclude
$$k \equiv k \;\;(\text{mod } n)\implies \delta_{0}^{n,p} = 1 \implies \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}u_{j}\delta_{j-k}^{n,p} = u_{k} $$
Since $0 = nm$ solves for $m=0$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
 Case 2: $k\geq n$
First we make a change of variables and denote $t \geq n$
$$t = n \cdot m + k $$
for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Clearly,
$$n \cdot m + k \equiv k \;\;(\text{mod } n) $$
Therefore, we get
$$\begin{align}
 t = n \cdot m + k &\implies n \cdot m + k \equiv k \;\;(\text{mod } n)  \\
 &\implies \delta_{j-t}^{n,p} = 1 \\
 &\implies \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}u_{j}\delta_{j-t}^{n,p} = u_{k} \\
 &\implies \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}u_{j}\delta_{j-k}^{n,p} = u_{k} 
\end{align} $$
$$\tag*{$\square$}$$

